# What browsers support javascript constants?

Tags: javascript, browser, cross-browser, constants, compatibility

I am building JavaScript application and decided to use `const` instead of `var` in my constant definitions something like this:

```js
const MAX_FILE_SIZE  = 50;
const MIN_FILE_SIZE  = 5;
const MAX_FILE_COUNT = 10;
...
```

That makes code more readable to me and I like this, but for some reason, my application failed to work on safari.

What browsers support the `const`?

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=const

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility

Comment: Seems data from these two sources is not matching for Android or did I get something wrong? One source says "No support" and the other says "Mosty supported"

Comment: I think the info at "Can I use" is slightly more accurate than MDN

Comment: I happened upon this question and answer and they were useful.  I've edited out the only part I can see as "opinion based" - the original question asked about "modern" browsers - and voted to reopen so the useful answer can be viewed by more people.

Comment: This is a great question and answer.  Looking at the edits, I'm curious why it was closed for being _opinion-based_.  The edits did make it better though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the information pages at [Can I use](http://caniuse.com/#feat=const) and [Mozilla Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const#Browser_compatibility), the JavaScript `const` feature is supported in:

- Google Chrome 20+ (Jun 2012)
- Mozilla Firefox 13+ (Jun 2012)
- Microsoft Internet Explorer 11+ (Oct 2013)
- Opera 12+ (Jun 2012)
- Safari 5.1+ (Jul 2011)

Comment: Thanks, what about mobile browsers? I am interested in Android Chrome and iOS Safari?

Comment: "Can I use" says that iOS Safari works if you avoid strict mode. It also says that it is fully supported in Android Chrome.